# uitableview from pushviewcontroller

Tags: uitableview, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a programmatically added uitableview in uiview which I call using a modalview controller which works fine. The same doesn't display data when I use a pushviewcontroller. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the table before the view will appear? If not, that might be the cause.